# Late bound closure variable available even when unset in parent scope

Tags: php, closures

I have been trying to understand closures. I understand that I can do late-binding on the closure variable by using a reference. It seems to work. But when I unset the variable in the parent scope, somehow the variable is still available and that also with intact data.

```
echo 'Start<br/>';
$name = 'Sheikh';
register_shutdown_function(function() use(&$name){
    echo 'Start RSF<br/>';
    echo 'Name is ' . $name.'<br/>';
    echo 'End RSF<br/>';
});
$name = 'Azad';
unset($name);
var_dump($name);
echo '<br/>';
echo 'End<br/>';
```

The output for the above is

```
Start
NULL
End
Start RSF
Name is Azad
End RSF
```

I do not expect the name variable to get printed.
If I do $name=NULL; in the parent scope then I get what I expect. 
Does unset() not actually unset a variable? Can someone explain what is happening here?

Comment: [There's a dedicated page in the manual on the subject.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php)